# Accessing values stored in HttpSession using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, httpsession

Here is my Spring MVC Controller code:

```
session.setAttribute("YourProperty", "arg1");
```

How can I access an attribute stored in my HttpSession using JavaScript?

I have tried using this code:

```
var property = <%=session.getAttribute("YourProperty")%>;
alert(property);
```

But it returns null.

Thanks

Comment: First of all you're being unsafe with the assignment to `property`. If it were a string the code would fail. The other thing is your set attribute *myProperty* on the session but you're getting *YourProperty* **which doesn't match**.

Comment: sorry it was my mistake..now i have edited my question..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var property="<%=session.getAttribute("MyProperty")%>";
alert(property);
```

Attribute names should match and since you are adding a string, you should add `"` around `<%=session.getAttribute("MyProperty")%>`, and the code will alert `arg1`.